# What eviction policy does NSCache use?

Tags: objective-c, caching

The docs say, "The NSCache class incorporates various auto-eviction policies, which ensure that a cache doesn’t use too much of the system’s memory. "

What are these policies?

Comment: Which docs? Does [Caching and Purgeable Memory](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/CachingandPurgeableMemory.html) answer your question?